# Having problems with datatypes. Can not use the > operator between an integer and a (function?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

As in title, seems to be a datatype issue that I can't get my head around. Any help would be appreciated.

randrange is choosing an index from 0-10, but it doesnt seem to return this as an integer value?

````
import random

numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] #long list of


def random_number():#function that generates a random number
    random_number = int
    index = random.randrange(0, 10)
    print("The number computer generated is " + numbers[index])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed()
    print("Welcome to Guess The Number game.\n"
          "The computer will generate a number from 1 to 10. \n"
          "You would have to guess it.\n"
          "Good luck!")
    random_number()
    number_guessed = int(input("Guess the number "))
    while number_guessed != random_number:
        if number_guessed > random_number:
            print("The number you guessed is bigger than the actual number.\n")
        if number_guessed < random_number:
            print("The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.\n")
        if number_guessed == random_number:
            break
            print("Well done! You guessed the correct number. Cya!")



    sys.exit(0)```
````

Comment: your random_number function is not returning anything and you need to store random_number function in a  variable named as random_number

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Too many answers via google are pointing me towards strange solutions.

Comment: Is `3` greater than `sum`? Who knows? But is `3` greater than `sum([1,1])`? Clearly, yes. You know because you're not comparing `1` to the function, you're comparing `1` to the function return value, which would be `2` for `sum([1,1])`, because `sum` uses `return` to give you that value.

Comment: Sorry @Grismar that went over my head. Not sure what you're trying to explain

Comment: Look up `return`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]  # long list of


def random_number():  # function that generates a random number
    random_number = int
    index = random.randrange(0, 10)
    number = numbers[index]
    print("The number computer generated is " + number)
    return int(number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed()
    print("Welcome to Guess The Number game.\n"
          "The computer will generate a number from 1 to 10. \n"
          "You would have to guess it.\n"
          "Good luck!")
    random_number = random_number()
    number_guessed = None
    while number_guessed != random_number or number_guessed is None:
        number_guessed = int(input("Guess the number "))
        if number_guessed > random_number:
            print("The number you guessed is bigger than the actual number.\n")
        if number_guessed < random_number:
            print("The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.\n")
        if number_guessed == random_number:
            break
            print("Well done! You guessed the correct number. Cya!")
```

Comment: @theWEANS still there are a lot of improvement needs to done and i think you can do it by your own

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems.

First, you need to return a value from your function to be able to use that value at somewhere else in your code.

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"] #long list of

def random_number():#function that generates a random number   
    return int(random.choice(numbers))
```

Secondly, you need to assign a `random_number` variable to the return value of `random_number()` function. And you need to ask for new input after every wrong guess.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed()
    print("Welcome to Guess The Number game.\n"
          "The computer will generate a number from 1 to 10. \n"
          "You would have to guess it.\n"
          "Good luck!")
    random_number = random_number()
    number_guessed = -1
    while number_guessed != random_number:
        number_guessed = int(input("Guess the number "))
        if number_guessed > random_number:
            print("The number you guessed is bigger than the actual number.\n")
           
        if number_guessed < random_number:
            print("The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.\n")
           
        if number_guessed == random_number:
            print("Well done! You guessed the correct number. Cya!")
            break
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Guess The Number game.
The computer will generate a number from 1 to 10. 
You would have to guess it.
Good luck!

Guess the number 5
The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.


Guess the number 6
The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.


Guess the number 7
The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.


Guess the number 8
The number you guessed is smaller than the actual number.


Guess the number 9
Well done! You guessed the correct number. Cya!
```

Comment: thanks, appreciate that. Sachin helped solve the first bit below. The second part about changing the input for incorrect guesses was is noted, but not necessary right now. Appreciate the help.